# Trigger function when element is visible, after scrolling down

Tags: javascript, triggers

I want to have a menu bar, which is shrinking its size via function.

My goal is to trigger the function, when the user has scrolled down, so that a specific element (maybe an invisible div) is theoretical visible.

Im specifically asking for a solution with basic JavaScript, without using jquery (because i dont understand it yet)
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can either detect the scroll itself or detect if an element scrolls into view. Which do you prefer?

Comment: if an element scrolls into view